# How to set default folder for IFileOpenDialog interface

Tags: c++, mfc, openfiledialog

I use the `MFC` interface `IFileOpenDialog` for selecting the source data file. Obviously, dialog is open in last used directory (folder).
I want to open the dialog in folder, the user send to function (the path in the parameter `lsCurFolder`). I have not find how to do it.

```
inline bool OpenFile(LPTSTR& pszFilePath, const FileType fTyp = MajCut, LPCTSTR lsCurFolder) {

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |
                                COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog* pFileDlg = NULL;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
                              IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileDlg));
        if (!SetTyp(fTyp, pFileDlg, L"Vyhledej soubor pro načtení"))
        {
            pFileDlg->Release();
            return false;
        }

        FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS opt;
        pFileDlg->GetOptions(&opt);
        if (pFileDlg->SetOptions(opt | FOS_STRICTFILETYPES) != S_OK)
        {
            pFileDlg->Release();
            return false;
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileDlg->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem* pItem;
                hr = pFileDlg->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath); //Volající musí zrušit volání voláním CoTaskMemFree
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileDlg->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}
```

Comment: In this case, use [`SetFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfolder) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Controlling the Default Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog#controlling-the-default-folder):

> Almost any folder in the Shell namespace can be used as the default folder for the dialog (the folder presented when the user chooses to open or save a file). Call [`IFileDialog::SetDefaultFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setdefaultfolder) prior to calling `Show` to do so.
>
> The default folder is the folder in which the dialog starts the first time a user opens it from your application. After that, the dialog will open in the last folder a user opened or the last folder they used to save an item. See [State Persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog#state-persistence) for more details.
>
> **You can force the dialog to always show the same folder when it opens, regardless of previous user action, by calling [`IFileDialog::SetFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfolder).** However, we do not recommended doing this. If you call `SetFolder` before you display the dialog box, the most recent location that the user saved to or opened from is not shown. Unless there is a very specific reason for this behavior, it is not a good or expected user experience and should be avoided. In almost all instances, [`IFileDialog::SetDefaultFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setdefaultfolder) is the better method.

So, for example:

```
...
IShellItem *pCurFolder = NULL; 
hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(lsCurFolder, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pCurFolder));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    pFileDlg->SetFolder(pCurFolder);
    pCurFolder->Release();
}
hr = pFileDlg->Show(NULL);
...
```